# Angular action dependent on result of other function http result

Tags: angular, rxjs

In my angular app I have several actions, which I can perform on templates:

- Add
- Edit
- Stop Tracking
- Start Tracking

Each one of them requires confirmation from server that I can perform it, in simple words flow looks like that:

> btn(click) -> checkStatus(http.resp) -> resp == true -> change view or another http request
>
> btn(click) -> checkStatus(http.resp) -> resp == false -> notify user that can't perform action

and I am struggling, with making my code not look like spaghetti, for this moment each functio looks like that:

template.component.ts

```
add() {
   this.api.makeRequest('checkStatus',{},config).subscribe(
       resp => {
         if (resp.statusIsOK) { /* add action code */} 
         else { this.dialog.open('Can\'t perform action')}
       }
   )
}

edit(id) {
   this.api.makeRequest('checkStatus',{},config).subscribe(
       resp => {
         if (resp.statusIsOK) { /* edit action code */} 
         else { this.dialog.open('Can\'t perform action')}
       }
   )
}

stopTracking(id, name) {
   this.api.makeRequest('checkStatus',{},config).subscribe(
       resp => {
         if (resp.statusIsOK) { /* stopTracking action code */} 
         else { this.dialog.open('Can\'t perform action')}
       }
   )
}

startTracking(id) {
   this.api.makeRequest('checkStatus',{},config).subscribe(
       resp => {
         if (resp.statusIsOK) { /* startTracking action code */} 
         else { this.dialog.open('Can\'t perform action')}
       }
   )
}
```

So my goal is to get this code out to other function named `checkStatus` and depending on result that it returns action code could be executed, so my vision is to make it like this

```
checkStatus() {
  this.api.makeRequest('checkStatus',{},config).subscribe(
    resp => {
      if (resp.statusIsOK) { return true;} 
      else { this.dialog.open('Can\'t perform action'); return false;}
    }
  )  
}

add() {
   if(this.checkStatus()) { /* add action code */}
}
```

but, the problem is that `checkStatus` is async, and I don't know the way to work it out.

Comment: Why don't you just make `add` async and add an `await` before the `checkStatus` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with the help of RxJS:

```js
import { tap, filter } from 'rxjs/operators';

checkStatus() {
  return this.api.makeRequest('checkStatus',{}, config)
    .pipe(
      tap((resp) => {
        if (resp.statusIsOK) {
          return;
        }

        this.dialog.open('Can\'t perform action');
      }),
      filter(resp => resp.statusIsOK),
    );
}

startTracking(id) {
  this.checkStatus().subscribe(() => {
    // This callback gets fired only if status is OK
    // startTracking action code
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
async add() {
    await this.checkStatus();

  }
```

it will solve your problem

Comment: he would have to return a promise from checkStatus to make this work

Answer (score 0):

You should return the `api.makeRequest` function as a promise so that you can then await the result and not have to subscribe.

```
async makeRequest(...){
  return this.http.get(...).toPromise()
}
```

*edit - as cannot access makeRequest directly example with additional function* `checkRequest()`

```
async checkRequest(...){ 
  return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
    this.api.makeRequest(...).subscribe(response=>
      resolve(response)
    )
  })
}
```

Both methods will return a promise which can be used in subsquent functions, such as

```
add(){
  const resp = await this.checkRequest('checkStatus',{},config)
  if(resp.statusIsOk){
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: I can't modify makeRequest function and it isn't async :(

Comment: Ok, in that case you can just add an intermediate function to do that for you, will update the example

Comment: I've added the function as 'checkRequest'. Let me know if it makes sense. It simply takes your makeRequest subscription and turns it into a promise